# JPG to PDF по маске. Как сделать? img2pdf

Tags: python

Имеются файлы:
1-page0.jpg
1-page1.jpg
1-page2.jpg
1-page3.jpg
2-page0.jpg
2-page1.jpg
2-page2.jpg
2-page3.jpg
Как сделать так чтобы объединить их в итоге как
1.pdf
2.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/ есть пример для вашего случая:

```
# multiple inputs (variant 2)
with open("name.pdf","wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(["test1.jpg", "test2.png"]))
```

Т.е. вам нужно передать список путей к картинкам.

Это удобно сделать через модуль `glob`, так вы получите список путей:

```
from glob import glob

imgs = glob("1-page*.jpg")
# ['1-page0.jpg', '1-page1.jpg', '1-page2.jpg', '1-page3.jpg']
```

Останется его передать в `img2pdf.convert`:

```
f.write(img2pdf.convert(imgs))
```

Comment: А как передать условие в качестве переменной? Например imgs = glob(i*+'.jpg'), где i = 1-page, 2-page... n-page

Comment: Просто форматируйте строку, `for i in range(9):` `imgs = glob(f"{i}-page*.jpg")`

Comment: @ gil9red    ` + `